# Use whenever with sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, whenever

I'm trying to get whenever to work with sinatra. When I run the `whenever` command, I get the generated cron tab. But the problem is, that in my sinatra app, I don't have a `script/runner` file, which is present in Rails.

How do I get this runner, or is there a whenever command to generate one?

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `rake` task in place of `script/runner`. The `Whenever` gem supports defining the job via a `rake` task ([and more in fact](https://github.com/javan/whenever#define-your-own-job-types))

Sample: 
    # config/schedule.rb

```
every 3.hours do
  rake "destroy_all"
end
```

and in your `Rakefile`: (for lack of good examples)

```
task :destroy_all do
  puts "Do not do this"
  # sh "rm -rf ."
end
```